# Django sign users in on closing and reopening of browser

Tags: django, django-authentication

In my Django website, if a user logs in using either the Django authentication system or with python-social-auth and then closes and reopens the website in a new tab the system identifies him as AnonymousUser. It's the same for opening the website in a second tab.

How can log him in automatically?

I see that the session does not expire.

I'm not sure which parts of my code are the most relevant to show here, please comment if something can help solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please look into below links, may be it can help you.
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the session cookie that Django automatically sets. The default Django login form lets the user chose to stay logged in after closing the browser, or be logged out automatically.

Leave it like that. When users are on public PCs, they need to be logged out as soon as they close the browser window. Otherwise, the next person will open the browser and be logged in as the previous user.

Answer (score 0):

This happens for 'session' cookies.  Check if Cookie.discard is getting set to True. More in cookielib module documentation in python documentation. Also Google 'cookie time to live'